# regex input only the allowed pattern (input text)

Tags: javascript, regex, input, regex-negation, regex-group

I have an input text field where I want to allow a pattern input example:

**hd546648** -ok

**Vg315248** - ok > 2 character what can be letter (lowercase, uppercase), and 6 character only numbers

```
on("input", "test", function(event) {
const invalidChars = /^[^A-Za-z]{1,2}\D{1,6}$/g;
ob = event.target;
if (invalidChars.test(ob.value)) {
  ob.value = ob.value.replace(invalidChars, "");
}
});
```

If I use only this `/^[^A-Za-z]{1,2}/g;` its working, I can type only letters to the text box, but if I add the number part, something is wrong.

What I want to do, if I type in the input box, replace any characters that is not A-Z or a-z, for first 2, and replace any other character that is not number 0-9 for 3-8. So for first 2 only enable letters and from 3 to 8 enable only numbers.

Comment: Probably a better idea is to use a `pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}"` that will perform final input check.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the pattern is validated only before submitting, but I want to allow the pattern when I am typing

Comment: I understand, but that is rather an annoying approach if you ask me.

Comment: You may use [`/^[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z](?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d(?:\d\d?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/0ZIFJy/1) with `test()` and if it does not match (returns false) disallow input. Else, allow input. But you will still have to enforce the final validation check, e.g. with `pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}"`.

Comment: It seems that OP wants `A12345` to be validated too since first character was replaced with `''`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesnt allow to input letters

Comment: Did you check the answer below? If you make a comment I can improve.

Comment: yeah, I see, now I am testing, how to modify my function to work

Comment: See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/od8mf82n/) with [JQuery masked input plugin](https://jsfiddle.net/od8mf82n/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, its a nice working example, but in pure javascript...

Comment: I'm not sure if that demo is what you expect. If that is what you want then earlier regex from Wiktor should solve it.

Comment: Reword your question. You are not looking for a way to replace unwanted characters with `''`, you are simply doing a partial match or something like that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it has a problem, if I make a click outside of the text box, then it will be deleted the (example first 3 characters)

Comment: Use `{autoclear: false}` - https://jsfiddle.net/od8mf82n/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex on the whole thing won't work, as each validation can invalidate another part of the input. This solution checks each character in turn, and truncates to the length of the last valid character. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/spwe4k21/

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);

  $("#userinput").keyup(function() {
    let input = $(this).val();
    let cleanedInput = cleanInput(input);
    $(this).val(cleanedInput);

  });
});

function cleanInput(input) {
  let tests = [/[a-z]/i, /[a-z]/i, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
  for (let i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] == undefined || !tests[i].test(input[i])) {
      return input.substring(0, i);
    }
  }

  return input.substring(0, tests.length);
}
```

Comment: on("input", "test", function(event) {
    input = event.target.value;
    const tests = [/[a-z]/i, /[a-z]/i, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
    for (let i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
      if (input[i] == undefined || !tests[i].test(input[i])) {
        input = input.substring(0, i);
      }
    }
  });
I cant make it to work

Comment: Assuming you can get and set the input value as you describe in your code, this should work for you: https://pastebin.com/H6eD9miB

Comment: there is a way to let the user input: k123456 and kk123456 with this function modified a bit? (enable to input one or two letter with 6 numeric?)

Comment: It sounds similar, but that's more complicated than this as you can no longer just check character by character. I think you should ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could split string to have those two separate parts in order to perform a substitution on both parts:</s>

**Update**:

```js
document.getElementById("re").onkeypress = function (e) {
  var keys = [8, 46, 37, 38]
  if (!keys.includes(e.keyCode))
    if (!/^[a-z]([a-z]\d{0,6})?$/i.test(e.target.value + e.key))
      e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<input id="re" placeholder="Type something">
```

Comment: The last input gives `d546648` as an output. This is an invalid pattern so it should be corrected again, no? It should end up as just `d` as there aren't enough letters to start the numeric part.

Comment: In my javascript function I cant figure out how to make workable, its possible to group or similar the invalid characters?

Comment: @SimonBrahan yeah you are right, when the user type in the input box, dont allow to enter anything else if its not correct, not matched the pattern

Comment: @almostokey So, do you want to accept `d546648`? or what should happen to `4d546648`?

Comment: @revo there is the working correct example maked by  Wiktor Stribiżew with jQuery, and I want to make it with pure javascript:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/od8mf82n/)

Comment: @revo in the Wiktor Stribiżew example you can test, when typing to the text box, do not let to enter anything else that not match the pattern

Comment: @almostokey Please check new update. Is there anything else left?

Comment: Yeah, now it works on the pattern part, but with the event keycodes I think its not a good resolution, example: you cannot use arrows

Comment: @almostokey Arrow keys? I can't see a problem even with IE8.

Comment: You cant move the cursor between the numbers in mozilla firefox

Comment: Then you can check for them. See update. @almostokey

Comment: @revo the right arrow key its still not working, thank you your time, Simon resolution its "independent of pressed keys"

Answer (score -2):

```js
regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,6}$/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).